# Check for incoming data in Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets

I'm writing a simple chat in Java, and I want to check if there is some data waiting on `BufferedReader`. I've read about NIO, but I didn't completely understand it. Here is some of my code:

```
public void Send(String data)
{
    out.println(data);
}

public String Recv()
{
    if (dataIncomming)
    {
        try {
            return in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Send: Error on BufferedReader.readLine() - IOException");
        }
    }
    else return "";
}
```

I don't know what to fill into `dataIncomming` ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [Stream.Available()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) method. You might also want to wait until the right amount of bytes is received and wait so the Thread is not running 100% of the time.

```
while(Stream.Available() != 0); //block until there is data

try{  
    return in.readLine();  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    System.err.println("Send: Error on BufferedReader.readLine() - IOException");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [InputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) method to check how many bytes have currently arrived on the socket's input stream.

```
public String Recv()
{
    if (in.available() > 0)
    {
        try {
            return in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Send: Error on BufferedReader.readLine() - IOException");
        }
    }
    else return "";
}
```